# How can I log into Git directly from Atom?

Tags: git, github, atom-editor

I've been using Git Desktop for a while. Works seamlessly using the SSH keys.
Recently got Atom and would like to use Atom for all Git work as well. But Git Push asks me to log in using username and password. That also fails.

How to configure Atom to use my SSH keys to login to Git and work seamlessly?

Also, How do I clone directly into Atom?

Comment: What URL did you use to clone the repo? --- Also, you can't clone _into_ atom, only clone to a directory which atom then uses.

Comment: Currently, I use Git Desktop to clone and then open the project in Atom. How do I clone into a directory using Atom, instead of Git Desktop?

Comment: This is the exact error message:
remote: Password authentication is not available for Git operations.
remote: You must use a personal access token or SSH key.
remote: See https://github.ibm.com/settings/tokens or https://github.ibm.com/settings/ssh
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.ibm.com/<org>/<project>.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403

Comment: Make sure you've set up ssh with github https://help.github.com/articles/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/.

Comment: Well, I've figured out that Atom does not work with enterprise GitHubs.
I was able to clone a Repo, but only the master branch was downloaded. Unable to change branch.
GitHub panel says no remote found.

Unless someone knows how to configure this.

Comment: Github says no remote found? Github is a website, git is the DVCS. Does the remote repo have multiple branches?

Comment: I meant the GitHub Tab/Pane in Atom. The message is "This repository does not have any remotes hosted on GitHub.com."

My only assumption is that Atom looks for the project only on github.com. There should be a way to point Atom to look at github.ibm.com, instead of github.com.

Yes, the repo has multiple branches and after cloning, I'm able to see only the master branch. Not able to Switch branches.

Comment: The Github integration in the Atom UI only works with github.com, not GH Enterprise. See https://github.com/atom/github/issues/270